# Location of heat conversion in heat engines

Tags: thermodynamics

If I put a large glass dome on a heap of coal, and burn it, I would expect the air to heat up certain amount.

But if I put a coal power plant to that dome, and use it to burn the same amount of coal, and power an electric oven outside the dome, I expect less temperature rise to the plant's dome in respect to the plain fire dome.

At which part of the power plant's machinery does this thermal energy loss happen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I'd call the energy you extract this way an energy "loss".

But imagine that you burn the coal and use that to boil water to steam.  The steam is made up of very energetic particles.  Given enough time, the particles will heat the materials inside the dome as they come to thermal equilibrium.

But in the power plant, we don't let them do that.  Before equilibrium happens, they are placed in a cylinder with a moving piston.  The steam does work on the piston.  As the steam expands, it cools.  The kinetic energy of the steam molecules is used to increase the kinetic energy of the piston.  Since the piston extends outside the dome (or is used to convert to another form of energy that leaves the dome), the energy remaining inside to convert to heat is less.

For most power plants, there is a steam expansion phase that is doing work against a turbine.  That is where the energy is harvested from the temperature gradient.

Comment: Like it was taught in school, I thought that any energy becomes heat some time, and can not be converted to any other energy back. However, as you said, the total amount of heat may decrease. If the heat stored in a fire and the heat in it's environment are added, they come out for more heat, as if the heat of the fire funneled to a piston and the heat of the piston's environment is added, after the piston is moved. So concentrated heat seems more valuable than spread heat, and spreading heat may reduce the total amount of heat stored, if done well (by a moving piston).

Comment: You can extract energy from heat only if you have a gradient, a set of two different temperatures.  The piston can pull energy, but it does so while equalizing the temperatures.  When the temperatures are equal, there is no more energy to be extracted.

Comment: But the equalized temperature would be lower, if compared to a system where there is no piston, and the temperature just equals out by itself?

Comment: Yes.  If the work is collected and used in your system, then the temperature would be identical to the case where it is not collected.  But instead some of the work is used outside the system (generating heat).  So the final temp in the system will be lower in that case.